# Get Azure Resource Details based on the Tag using Rest API

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I can able to fetch the resource details using the Azure CLI command. However, is there a way to fetch the specific resource details using Azure API Management URL?
I have listed out the Azure API Management link to get the tag details. I need
Azure API Management to get the resource details via API. Please help me.

**CLI command**
(Get-AzResource -Tag @{ "ApplicationID"="XXX"})

**Output**
Name              : sample-dev-func
ResourceGroupName : example-rg
ResourceType      : Microsoft.Web/sites
Location          : eastus
ResourceId        : /subscriptions/xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/resourceName
etc..,

**Azure Management API**

[https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/tagNames?api-version=2021-04-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/tagNames?api-version=2021-04-01)

Answer (score 1):

> However, is there a way to fetch the specific resource details using
> Azure API Management URL?

Yes. You can use [`Resources - List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list) REST API to get the list of resources. This API supports filtering by tag name/value.

From the same link:

> Resources can be filtered by tag names and values. For example, to
> filter for a tag name and value, use $filter=tagName eq 'tag1' and
> tagValue eq 'Value1'. Note that when resources are filtered by tag
> name and value, the original tags for each resource will not be
> returned in the results. Any list of additional properties queried via
> $expand may also not be compatible when filtering by tag names/values.
>
> For tag names only, resources can be filtered by prefix using the
> following syntax: $filter=startswith(tagName, 'depart'). This query
> will return all resources with a tag name prefixed by the phrase
> depart (i.e.department, departureDate, departureTime, etc.)

**Tip**: Azure CLI essentially is a wrapper of Azure REST API. If you want to see the actual request sent by the CLI command and the response received, simply execute your CLI command with `--debug` switch. You will get all the details.

Comment: Gaurav, Thank you for your reply. I can able filter by tag using API Management.

Comment: However, I have run the below command to get verbose (To know the request send by CLI). But I do not get any verbose details. But I do get the resource details. I want to see what this command doing in backgrou.   "az resource list --tag AppID=XXX --query [] --verbose" Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, my bad! Actually you will need to use `--debug` switch. Please try to use that instead of `--verbose`. I have edited my answer as well.